# Can Notepad++ show pagebreaks (Win 7)

Tags: windows-7, notepad++

How, if even possible, can you set Notepad++ to view page-breaks?  This can be done in Microsoft Word in the page-break view.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767545/does-notepad-show-all-hidden-characters. The answer there is probably the one you need as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to get Notepad++ to draw a line across the screen to represent page-breaks like Word does, and I'm not aware of a plugin which adds this.

You can get it to display non-printing characters by `View`->`Show Symbol`->`Show All Characters`, which will let you see where the breaks are, but this will also display all the *other* non-printing characters like line feeds.

Comment: You're true. Get your upvote;) @Kairan you can mark this as Answer.

Answer (score -1):

Notepad++ is not a WYSIWYG document creation tool like Word is. A page break implies a page of paper, and Notepad++ was not designed for the purpose of paper document creation.